# Highchart Y-axis max length not apply

Tags: highcharts

In highchart, i apply min-max for both axis. But when i generate graph, it is not apply.

my jsfiddle link:
[My Custom highchart link](http://jsfiddle.net/fehjnp5a/14/)

I add this for y-axis length.

```
min: 0,max: 10,
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the primary axis? All you have there is a title.

Comment: Disable alignTicks property http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.alignTicks

Comment: @ Mike Zavarello, Without primary axis, Graph is not design.

Comment: @morganfree this is not working

Comment: can you solve it in jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/fehjnp5a/14/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fehjnp5a/15/ alignTicks to false in chart options. The axis ranges from 0 to 10.